# What does isLocal() actually do in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I've been looking into [Laravel Telescope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/telescope#configuration) and it mentioned the ability of being able to run only in one's local environment as opposed to production by including the following code snippet in `AppServiceProvider`.

```
public function register()
{
    if ($this->app->isLocal()) {
        $this->app->register(TelescopeServiceProvider::class);
    }
}
```

This works fine but I am trying to figure out what exactly the `isLocal()` method does. So far, I have not been able to find much information.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `.env` file you would have a `APP_ENV` set to `local` on your development environment and it will be different on other servers. So `isLocal` just checks if that is set to local or not.

[Here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L512) is the answer from the repository.

To check for a different env other than local or production use this helper function:

```
config('app.env') // get the env
```

for production there is a `isProduction()` helper function on the app instance.

Comment: I see.. I am assuming then that I could add a check to see if I am in the staging environment, correct?